# CentOS Atomic Host Cockpit kubernetes

Tags: centos, kubernetes, atomic, host, cockpit

After  installation cockpit & cockpit-kubernetes on CentOS 7 web dashboard contains "machines", "dashboard" and "cluster" tabs. But on CentOS Atomic only firt two present. How to setup cockpit/kubernetes container? Like cockpit/ws

```
#atomic run cockpit/ws
```

Comment: As the answer below explains, this is because of what RHEL is doing with Kubernetes.  There should be ways around this, though, but I haven't had time to figure them out.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

"All-in-one kubernetes installs are still supported, but Red Hat no longers supports Kubernetes clusters."

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-host/7/single/installation-and-configuration-guide/#operating_system_content)